# The import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream cannot be resolved in eclipse Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to use [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) from  but eclipse can find this library.
In preference i changed the jdk to 1.8.0 but i still see this issue.
When i write import java.io. I get only 3 options:

1)IOException

2)PrintScreen

3)UnsupportedEncodingException

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
The code that I'm using

```
package mypkg;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
class Util   {

}
```

I have errors on ByteArrayInputStream and StringBufferInputStream

Comment: try restarting your IDE.

Comment: Already restared it didn't work

Comment: Show us the full code of the class that does not work.

Comment: i had the same error what i did: remove the file from the editor, close eclipse, start it, and load the file. and then the errors disappeared. magic...